# Як твориться скорочення імен в українській мові?

Tags: власні-назви, скорочення

В українській мові у кожного імені існує кілька варіацій скорочення (приклад: Станіслав - Стас, Стасьо, Стах тощо).

Чи є такі скорочення ознакою зросійщення української мови (адже в російській мові скорочення імен чуємо ще частіше), чи така лексична особливість також є природньою для української?

Якщо це також лексична особливість української мови, то як саме відбувається творення таких скорочень?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ні, це явище не є зросійщенням, це стовідсотково. В українській мові взагалі багато зменшувальних форм, і, як правильно вказує Вікіпедія, такі форми існують навіть для дієслів («їстоньки»). До того ж, дуже кумедно звучало б, якщо, скажімо, дружина завжди зверталася до чоловіка виключно «Володимире» або «Миколо».
Щоправда, поміж зменшувальних форм власних імен є ті, що запозичені з російської мови. По-перше, це форми імен на -ша: Маша, Саша, Ксюша. По-друге, іноді зустрічаються форми з фонологічним складом, що є неприродним для української мови: Лєна, Свєта, Льоша. Натомість, є такі форми, яких або зовсім немає у російській мові, або вони навпаки запозичені з української: форми на -сь/-ся (Петрусь, Гануся, Олесь/Олеся; порівняйте з формами загальних іменників — матуся, татусь, дідусь тощо); своєрідні форми (Марічка, процитовані вами Стасьо, Стах); форми на -к- від повних імен (Марійка, Софійка, Наталка, Оленка); форми на -ко під наголосом (Сашко, Грицько) та ін.

Answer (score 3):

Я не бачу підстав вважати, що традиція вживати скорочені (Олесь ← Олександр, Чіпка ← Нечипір), пестливі (Івасик ← Іван, Марічка ← Марія) чи змінені (Ярина ← Ірина) форми імен походить з російської. По-перше, ми маємо безліч форм імен, що не притаманні російській. По-друге, це явище, загалом кажучи, притаманне багатьом народам (англ. Bob ← Robert, Jack ← John; фр. Margaux/Margot ← Marguerite; нім. Fritz ← Friedrich/Frederick).

Хоча *окремі* варіанти, звісно, цілком можуть бути запозиченими.

Щодо механізмів творення, на жаль, відповісти не можу (певен, що існує декілька механізмів; але поки не знайшов літератури, що добре б їх описувала).